# wget cannot locate file in different domain

Tags: wget

I'm using `wget` to download file with the recursive option (`-r`) and enabling the recursion to go to other domains (`-H`). When it cannot find some file, wget just keeps trying

```
--2013-05-05 13:38:52--  http://clnet.ucla.edu/robots.txt
Resolving clnet.ucla.edu... 128.97.168.150
Connecting to clnet.ucla.edu|128.97.168.150|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

--2013-05-05 13:39:14--  (try: 2)  http://clnet.ucla.edu/robots.txt
Connecting to clnet.ucla.edu|128.97.168.150|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.
```

down to try 10, and so on. Is there a way to tell wget just to ignore this file?

Comment: To ignore that specific file or any file that fails the first download?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Any file that fails the first download

Comment: Did you try `--tries=1` as an option?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I see. That should work.